# Is there a way to deliver streaming content from a Windows Phone 8 application?

Tags: video-streaming, windows-phone-8, smooth-streaming, azure-media-services

Is there a way to deliver streaming content from a Windows Phone 8 application using Windows Azure Media Services and Smooth Streaming. [Here is an example with an C# application](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/media-services/how-to-guides/media-services-dotnet/#header-12)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could use Media Player Framework for Windows Phone 8: http://playerframework.codeplex.com/releases/view/97645

It has Smooth Streaming playback capability and it integrates with PlayReady content protection.

Comment: Thanks. I used Media Player Framework for WP8 to display streaming content, now Im searching a way to deliver streaming content from the same application WP8. I didn't find any samples of Smooth Streaming playback.

Comment: There is no WP8 SDK for the service (sending video to Windows azure media services). The best you would do is to set up a service backend (a hosted site to receive video). And send video over from your phone using REST for instance.

Comment: https://github.com/WindowsAzure-TrainingKit/Demo-BuildClips this demo app is sending video from a WIndows 8 device but the service end should be the same when you try to use WP8.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll try it. So I can't send video from WP8 app and use Smooth Streaming to broadcast this video live on other devices?

Comment: Live streaming is not available in WAMS yet. But you can record video on Wp8, send to WAMS to encode, and broadcast to all devices in various format (Smooth Streaming, HLS and etc).